# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Bluetooth not detecting any device

Tags: bluetooth

I am having HP Probook Laptop. Since I have installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS, my laptop is not connecting with any device using bluetooth. Other device is also not detecting my laptop. I have no option to boot windows on my laptop as I use ubuntu 14.04 LTS only. I have tried many solutions provided on different online forums. But those are not helpful for me. I am having hardware and drivers setting properly. Still the problem persists. The issues is haunting me since long.
Please help me to solve this problem.
Regards

These are the outputs of the command suggested.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18e3]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

Bus 002 Device 010: ID 3938:1032  
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 054c:0b7d Sony Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0cf3:311f Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f2:b3c8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 03f0:5607 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of **dmesg | grep -i blue** is as follows

```
[   16.954778] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   16.954806] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.954825] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.954827] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.954832] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   20.495498] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.495509] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.495514] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   20.520230] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.520234] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   20.520242] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

`dmesg | grep ath3k` does not give any output

`rfkill list` returns

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

uname -a retruns

```
Linux ubuntu-HP-ProBook-440-G1 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your quetion and add outout if `kspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @pilot6 I'm on my phone so can't test 'kspci" but do you mean 'lspci'?

Comment: It is a typo `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: And also output of `dmesg | grep ath3k` and `rfkill list`.

Comment: These are two separate commands. `rfkill list` should output something if you entered it correctly.

Comment: And what is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Now it is clear.

Comment: Ok. Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never updated your system. You have an ancient kernel that doesn't have support of the device. The support has been added by [this commit](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.c?id=efe73383e13d1231560e6da9028e630ee14699c8)

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You should get the `3.13.0-126` kernel that has support of this device.

Comment: Whether running the command mentioned above automatically will update the kernel or I have to do something in addition

Comment: It is all you need. It will update the system. You need to reboot after it finishes.